# Remove padding on UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

On a `UITableViewCell` with `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` styling, I'm setting the `imageView.image`, `textLabel.text`, and `detailTextLabel.text`. There's white padding all around the cell. How do I get rid of the padding so all my images touch each other like the Youtube app below?

[image]

Comment: You should mark @Borut's answer as the working one, because it's much simpler and the the main reason for your issue.

Comment: After wasting a full day on this! This solution also worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103155/ios7-tableview-cell-imageview-extra-padding

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this would be to subclass `UITableViewCell` and override the `-layoutSubviews` method to do something like this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
  //have the cell layout normally
  [super layoutSubviews];
  //get the bounding rectangle that defines the position and size of the image
  CGRect imgFrame = [[self imageView] frame];
  //anchor it to the top-left corner
  imgFrame.origin = CGPointZero;
  //change the height to be the height of the cell
  imgFrame.size.height = [self frame].size.height;
  //change the width to be the same as the height
  imgFrame.size.width = imgFrame.size.height;
  //set the imageView's frame (this will move+resize it)
  [[self imageView] setFrame:imgFrame];

  //reposition the other labels accordingly
}
```

Comment: this method works perfectly. sometimes it also needs to invoke layoutSubviews on subviews, especially when the width or height is adjusted.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove table separator:

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 2):

In iOS8 you can set

```
tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
```

in code, or from Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1):

Try reducing the UITableView's row height in interface builder or code so that there is no padding.
I had to increase the padding i did so in the interface builder for the tableview. 
However Daves answer might give you more control over modifying the cell view.