# Trouble with iOS group table

Tags: ios, iphone, cell

I'm new to iOS programming, and I'm struggling to get a table to look like the one I've designed.  I'm using a grouped table, but I can't figure out how to get varying height and how to reduce the padding.  Does anyone know a better way to do this than a grouped table?  I've attached a link to the image showing what I'm trying to do.

https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0Bx7qAEhjSDyPYTQyYWUxNjMtMDIxNi00OGM0LTgxODgtMWIxMTcwYmJjNjI3&hl=en_US

Answer (score 0):

That looks like you want to use a one row per section and a different height for each section's row.

The varying height comes from using a different custom cell for each section.

Answer (score 0):

To get individual row height:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Padding is more complex, you have to override UITableView. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769184/remove-padding-on-uitableviewcell) question.

Comment: try messing with `sectionHeaderHeight` and `sectionFooterHeight` before you derive from UITableView.